# Sqlite ordering a numeric column startinng by 1 for each category

Tags: sqlite

I have a table called groups ( i fill with this data a treeview )

```
id type description orden description
-- ---- ----------- ----- -----------
1  1    Aninals     1     Elefant
2  1    Animals     2     Tiger 
......
25 1    Animals     25    Horse 
26 2    Fish        1     Jaws 
27 2    Fish        2     
....

Deleting, inserting, i have jumps in the column orden.
1  1    Aninals     1     Elefant
2  1    Animals     3     Tiger 
......
25 1    Animals     27    Horse 


I need do somehing like this:

//animals
Update grupos set orden = (counter ascendent starting by 1) where type = 1 order by orden
//fish
Update grupos set orden = (counter ascendent starting by 1) where type = 2 order by orden
...
```

to get the column orden without number jumps.

Can some one help with this sql statement ?

Comment: It is usually a bad idea to change IDs. What do you have against jumps?

Comment: I don't want to change id's. The column order is the order of the animals. In the treeview you can drag up or down the animals, i change the order.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked that `id` is not `orden`. But why do you *need* to reassign the order numbers? When a row is moved between two other rows, you need to renumber in your program anyway.

Comment: Yes, but with some errors renumerating, i have jumps in the order: I try to make something like: Update grupos set orden = ( select count(*) from grupos b where id >=b.id and tipo = 1) where tipo = 1. All the orden clumn has the sum of records of type = 1.

Answer (score 0):

For each entry, just count how many entries with the same or smaller order number there are.
(In SQLite, UPDATE statements are not atomic when reading from the same table, so we have to construct the new order numbers in a different table.)

```
BEGIN;

CREATE TEMP TABLE NewOrden AS
SELECT id,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM grupos AS g2
        WHERE g2.type   = grupos.type
          AND g2.orden <= grupos.orden
       ) AS orden
FROM grupos;

UPDATE grupos
SET orden = (SELECT orden
             FROM NewOrden
             WHERE id = orden.id);

DROP TABLE NewOrden;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Thanks very much.This is that i need.